# MVVM Light code snippet (mvvvminpcset).Need an example of usage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In MVVM Light tool kit along with *mvvmincp* there's such code snippet called *mvvminpcset*.

**inpcset** snippet itself

```
 public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

        private bool _myProperty = false;

        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(MyPropertyPropertyName, ref _myProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Could anyone show an example of usage?
I would like to know what practical benefit does usage of mentioned above snippet bring.

Thanks

**inpc** simple

```
 public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

    private bool _myProperty = false;
    public bool MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _myProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

**inpcset** with method

```
  public const string MovedPropertyName = "Moved";

        private bool _moved = false;
        public bool Moved
        {
            get
            {
                return _moved;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(MovedPropertyName, ref _moved, value);

                MovedOn();
            }
        }


        private void MovedOn()
        { 

          // do something

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just syntactic sugar for the way you usually implement INPC:

```
private bool _MyProperty;
public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return this._MyProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (this._MyProperty != value)
        {
            this._MyProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MyProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer the usual/verbose implementation, rather than Set, for the sole reason that I like being able to place breakpoints that get hit only when the value of the backing property actually changes.

Comment: but what is practical difference between inpcset and simple inpc (see first post updated)? And in which case are you using inpcset?

Comment: None (Edit: nothing major). If you go to the implementation you'll see it's the same code. `Set` is just a shortcut. Edit: their implementation is a bit more verbose and makes sure to use the default comparer and such, but it's pretty much "set the value if it's not the same value and raise property changed event"

Comment: As @asaf92 points out, there's not really any practical difference other than the fact that some people think it looks better. Functionally it's doing exactly the same thing. WPF is often criticized for being too verbose (unfairly, IMO, but that's another conversation). MVVM frameworks like Caliburn Micro etc actually go to significant lengths to address this, at the expense of visibility into the workings of the underlying mechanics. The case you've posted here is no different, it's just a first step in trying to reduce what is perceived by some developers as unnecessary and repetitive code.

Comment: BTW I personally prefer the shorter version as well as the use of expression body statements. It makes View-Models a lot more concise. However I do understand why people don't want to change habits/code-base over something so minor

Comment: so could anyone explain how to call a method when property changed?

Comment: In the code I posted above the call to `RaisePropertyChanged` is just a regular function call, nothing to stop you calling any other functions there. If you want something else to respond to the value changing (i.e. an instance of a different class) then simply have it subscribe to the view model's `PropertyChanged` event, which is what gets raised whenever the class calls `RaisePropertyChanged` (or `Set`, in your case).

Comment: @DeputyOfCopyPaster In MVVMLight, Set() returns a boolean to indicate if the value was actually changed or not so you could write something like get { if (Set(ref _backingField, value)) { MyMethod(); } }

Comment: @Peregrine, like this? See update in the first post(impcset with method).

Comment: In that example MoveOn() will be called each time the property is set, whether the value is actualy updated or not.

Comment: There is also an overload of Set() that doesn't require the property name to be passed - instead it relies on CallerMemberName. Using a hard coded string for the property name is only going to lead to issues down the line. If you really must pass the property name, use NameOf() instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set() comapre new value with current and fire only if different
2. also Set() send both event

```cs
    RaisePropertyChanging(propertyExpression);
    field = newValue;
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyExpression);
```

and if you have a code style convention you can force using only one of the methods

1. MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty" is fragile against refactoring you can use nameof(MyProperty) or () => this.ID
2. with Set() you have 1 code line against several line of code, it is also place to add bug
3. probably you will use code snippet to generate code for INPC property and there are no difference at this point

so you decide use this one

```
public int Id
{
    get => _entity.Id;
    set => Set(ref _entity.Id, value);
}
```

updated

i think you was misleaded with the name of INPC, because MVVM separate how you update view and execute commands

1. if you have view model you can update view. you set property and setter notify view to update
2. when view need send something back, in example, button click, view use ICommand property in your view model to call something

there are to many details, i thing you need take in hand some working [example](https://github.com/barrylapthorn/MvvmLightExamples) and read about mvvm something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

Comment: My problem is I have no clue how do I call a method when Property changed  (ViewModel).